# how to implement window based authentication for web service

Tags: asp.net, security

how to implement window based authentication for web service

Answer (score 1):

The same way you implement it for a web application. See:

- [ASP.NET 3.5 Windows-Based Authentication](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-3-5-Windows-Based-Authentication.id-310905.html)
- [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)